# How to solve: Android ClassFormatError for RunConfiguration in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, execution, run-configuration

appreciate some help here.

just installed Android Studio 1.5.1 (after using 1.2). I then created a new project to try it out and get the following displayed in the event log:

> 7:15:26 PM ClassFormatError: update failed for AnAction with ID=RunConfiguration: com/intellij/execution/ExecutionTargetManager

The Run icon is absent from the toolbar:

[image: Android Studio toolbar]

and I can't run the app, even if I select Run>Run from the toolbar (nothing happens except the error message is displayed in the event log.)

so, really would appreciate some help to solve this problem.

thanks

clive

Comment: perhaps i should also mention that i get this message in event log as well: 7:33:32 PM ClassFormatError: update failed for AnAction with ID=RunConfiguration: Invalid constant pool index 514 in class file com/intellij/execution/ExecutionTargetManager

Answer (score 0):

Check yout Java Version you use and the compile version you use in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

You can right click over the toolbar and select customize menu and toolbar.after you can add your run icon on menu toolbar. Or you can use the short key Shift+F10 in linux and windows or cmd+F10 in mac.
And also check the minimum SDK version on your project gradle.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the response but I managed to get it working.

after installing 1.5 I had a number of errors which were apparently caused by the path (to android studio sdk) being too long (apparently exceeding windows limit of 260 characters). I then renamed my windows folders to shorten the path. The errors went away but the classFormatError then appeared, effectively removing the run option. I now assume that this had something to do with my renaming the folders in the path. anyhow, I reinstalled android studio 1.5 and now everything is working.